# Generating new exponential distribution from different exponential distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, distribution

I have a numpy array in range [0,1000]  with exponential distribution with lambda_x, I want to transform this numpy array to an array  with different  exponential distribution lambda_y. How can I find a function that does this mapping?

tried to use the inverse function but it didnt work.

```py
def inverse(X, lambd):
    """Inverse  of exponential distribution """
    return -np.log(1-X)/lambd
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by transform your array, which I understood was a list of values between 10 and 1000 supposedly from an expinential distribution (which is odd because the exponential distribution has a range of 0, +inf). Are you trying to generate a sample of an exponential distribution with lambda_y mean?

Comment: Corrected to [0,1000] and yes Im trying to generate new distribution with different lambda. lets say lambda_y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as taking your original exponentials *X* and scaling them by multiplying by λ<sub>x</sub>/λ<sub>y</sub> to produce *Y*'s.

A well known mechanism is to generate exponentials via [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). The second example on that page shows that if you generate U's which are uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 (where 100*U corresponds to the percentiles of the distribution) and transform them using the formula -ln(1 - U) / λ, you will get exponentials with rate λ.  If λ is λ<sub>x</sub> it yields your *X* distribution, and if λ is λ<sub>y</sub> it yields the *Y* distribution.  Hence rescaling by the ratio of the lambdas will convert from one to the other for a given percentile.